# installed miniforge and then uninstalled using brew

Tags: homebrew

I have installed `brew` successfully. Then, I ran the following command `brew install miniforge` and then `conda install -y jupyter`

Everything was installed correctly. I was also told by `brew` to copy path with commands starting with `echo` and `eval` which I did.

Now when type `jupyter notebook` in the terminal, I am told that `zsh: command not found: jupyter`, what is the problem?

Comment: What is your ~/.zshrc and your $PATH

Comment: What exactly did you do with the echo/eval part which brew and/or conda recommended to do?

Comment: Did you restart the shell after adding the homebrew bits to your configuration?

Comment: @nohillside I ran them

Comment: @MarcWilson No I didn't

Comment: Does it work in a new tab, or after restarting Terminal?